How can I extract raw data in excelsheet from a histogram in anylogic?
How can I extract raw data in excel sheet from a histogram in anylogic? I tried adding a dataset and excel sheet file to the main project. I identified an agent that feeds the data to the histogram but I'm unsure to extract that data into excel sheet
I'm new to anylogic

You mean write to an Excel file? First check the help and example models, they cover a ton already: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/excel-file.html#excel-file . Also consider first writing to the model dbase and then to Excel, that is even easier: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/internal-database-index.html

oh, and best ask open-ended "how do I" questions over in the LinkedIn forum, SOF is best for specific technical questions, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community . Welcome to the community, we are all happy to help :)
